# keda operator does not find my connection string

Tags: azureservicebus, keda

I'm using KEDA with a servicebus with a minimal setup, but when I push a scaleobject, the operator tells me that connection string is missing. So no HPA is created and of course no scaling. I really don't know what I'm missing

```
{"level":"error","ts":1585898856.2814944,"logger":"controller-runtime.controller","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"scaledobject-controller","request":"keda/azure-servicebus-queue-scaledobject","error":"error getting scaler for trigger #0: error parsing azure service bus metadata: no connection setting given",
```

I tried different format, with or without the entityPath and I don't [understand Go](https://github.com/kedacore/keda/blob/master/pkg/scalers/azure_servicebus_scaler.go)) very well but I should only get there is the connectionstring is empty

```yaml
apiVersion: keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: azure-servicebus-queue-scaledobject
  labels:
    deploymentName: my-deploy
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    deploymentName: my-deploy
  pollingInterval: 5
  minReplicaCount: 2   
  maxReplicaCount: 10  
  triggers:
  - type: azure-servicebus
    metadata:
      queueName: keda
      connection: Endpoint=sb://test-keda.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=reader;SharedAccessKey=BLABLABLA;EntityPath=keda
      queueLength: "5"
```

Any idea of what I am missing ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ok I'm dumb

you need to pass the name of the secret containing the connection string, not the string itself

explanation here: https://keda.sh/docs/scalers/azure-service-bus/